# Creating a library for Ubuntu touch

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, libraries

I am a software developer that usually deals with Windows products (C#) and Android products (Java) and they both have a relatively easy was to write and use libraries across projects, C# having `.dll`'s and Java having `.jar`'s.

I have background in all sorts of languages, C++, python, Java, C#, web development (which includes JavaScript) so developing for Ubuntu Touch shouldn't be to much of a challenge for me.

And then I started...

What I want to do is write a library in C++ (Are there any other languages I could use?) that I can use across my applications (For Ubuntu Touch). I know what I need to do programming wise. But when it comes to using the library what do I need to do? That part of it is what is getting me.

My question really is, how do I write a library and then import it into my application?

I see that there is a dependencies tab in the project manager in QtCreator, but not to sure what else I need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some documentation from QtCreator about how to do this: http://qt-project.org/wiki/How_to_create_a_library_with_Qt_and_use_it_in_an_application

Comment: This appears to be what I want, shall try it put tonight.

Comment: Try it out I meant**